# Gun Barrel Pressure Distribution

Tags: projectile

I am trying to design a gun barrel and simulate its fatigue properties in a FEM solver like ansys. I have the basic geometric data of the barrel and shell. I found out that using internal ballistics we can theoretically calculate the variation of pressure in time using something called Vallier–Heydenreich Empirical Formulation. However, I am not able to get the exam empirical relations and/or coefficient values for this.

Comment: Did you read this paper http://psrcentre.org/images/extraimages/22%20612121.pdf ?